# Prove that $(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^{2}-(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})^{2}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Given $x=a+b,y=a-b$, prove that $$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}$$

$z=f(x,y)$

It is the first time that I've seen this weird greek sign.
is it something like $dx/dy$ ? what is going on in this question?
I know that is $d/dy$ is more like an operator than a fraction. Or perhaps I'm just mixing up 2 different things..? sorry it just that I'm not familiar with this particular sign...

Comment: What "weird greek sign" are you referring to? Do you know what are "[partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative)"?

Comment: I assume they mean the partial derivative symbol - $\partial$ - which is just a stylised letter 'd'.

Comment: How is $z$ related to $x$ and $y$?

Comment: This is most easily done using the multivariable version of the chain rule. But if you haven't come across that one yet, then it may take quite some explaining...

Comment: $\partial$ is not greek, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%82

Comment: If you have never seen the symbol $\partial$ before, where is this exercise from?

Comment: @Jack from the book

Comment: @Jack Yes, I´m so sorry.

Comment: @user6394019 From what book? What tetbook author in their right mind would give you a problem like this without properly introducing partial derivatives and the associated notation?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} = 2\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial b}-\frac{\partial y}{\partial b} = 2\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}-\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} = 0\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial b}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial b} = 0\\
$$

and

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}
$$

then

$$
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)=\cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

$x=a+b,\quad y=a-b\implies a=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\quad \text{and}\quad b=\frac{1}{2}(x-y)$

By chain rule $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}$$ and $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}$$

So $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial z}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial b})$$ and $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial b}(-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial z}{\partial a}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial b})$$

Therefore $$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{4}\{(\frac{\partial z}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial b})^2-(\frac{\partial z}{\partial a}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial b})^2\}=\frac{1}{4}(4\frac{\partial z}{\partial a}\frac{\partial z}{\partial b})=\frac{\partial z}{\partial a} \frac{\partial z}{\partial b}$$
Hence $$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^{2}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial a} \frac{\partial z}{\partial b}$$